# Problem With large prints on Lulzbot Taz6

Tags: heated-bed, software, fdm, hotend, lulzbot

I have got a Lulzbot TAZ6 3 days ago. Last night I started a print which is 21 hours long and when I returned check on it this afternoon it was a complete mess.
These are the objects that I wanted to print:
[image]

I used Cura LUlzbot edition for printing this, the settings I have opted are:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I need to print them with 100% infill for my project. I printed it over USB, and the cura was still running when I checked now, so i guess its not because of the computer shutdown. This used to happen when I tried printing these on Lulzbot KITTAZ i have, but its not working so I got TAZ6. Please let me know where i'm going wrong.
[image]
This was the state of the print(some of it was sticking to the printbed, this picture was taken after i removed it from the printbed)

**Edit:**

Thanks for the suggestion. I have calibrated the extruder and tried to print only the vertical cylinder. I have changed only one setting, changed the extrusion multiplier to .99. I kept the infill density to 100%(my project needs a cylinder to be completely filled without any air gaps) to see which of those two has greater influence on the print quality.   All the other settings were the same
here is the result(After I saw this I cancelled the print):
[image]
[image]

Like you suggested the infill is overflowing. What should I do next, i'm concerned if it is printed with reduced infill percentage its density will decrease. Shall I try to print it with 97% and see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Unluckily - for as much information on your settings you share - it is very **difficult to diagnose the problem without knowing how the print failed**.  Did a piece become dislodged? Did the nozzle caught onto a printed piece? Did the head began extrude in mid air? ...?

However this are my guesses:

- From your temp settings it looks like you are printing ABS.  If this is the case, **have you placed your printer in an enclosure**?  With ABS, It is very very difficult (if not impossible) to print anything above "small", without an enclosure.
- **Printing 100% infill is normally a bad idea**.  If you are doing it for strength, then you should know that the strength gains are progressively smaller on anything above 60%.  100% infill also means that unless your extrusion is perfectly calibrated (which I suspect it may not be the case, given that your setting is the default 100%) any amount of overextrusion will likely let the nozzle "catch".  Finally, 100% extrusion also increases the warping forces on the piece considerably.
- **Printing a cylinder "laying down" is hard**: you basically have zero adhesion to the printing bed and must rely on the support material to stabilise your part.  But the support material is designed *not* to bond securely to the main piece and it will be unable to counterbalance any "curling up" that your part may experience due to thermal contraction.

So, my suggestions:

- **Use an enclosure** (even a simple cardboard box on top of the printer will do for a starter).  *Definitively* use an enclosure if you are printing with ABS
- **Calibrate your extruder**.  [Here](https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/how-to-calibrate-your-extruder) is a handy guide. :)
- **Reduce your infill density** to something between 60% and 97%.
- **Print your parts one at a time**, start from the vertical cylinder and - when you have got that right - try the horizontal one.
- If you must print one of the two horizontal...

  - **Increase the support density considerably**, and diminish the Z-distance between support and print to the bare minimum.  If your edition of cura has that setting, use support interfaces at full density.
  - Alternatively eliminate the headache completely and **print two semi-cylinders instead** (cut the cylinder in half along its length, printing them with the "cut" as their base) **and glue them together afterwards**.  If you are using ABS you can "weld" them with acetone instead.

Comment: Hi please go through the edit, I have posted the results after a few changes in the settings.

Comment: @vedanarayana - The extrusion rate still does not look correct.  You may wish to check your hot end does not leak.  Check that nothing similar to what happened to [this user](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/5288/9134) is also happening to you.  Additionally: if it density of the part that you are after, you could print the cylinder hollow and fill the pocket with sand while pausing the print mid way (or printing two halves and gluing them a|terwards, while keeping the infill below 100%.